# Redirect 301 .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Below is my htaccess and Redirect 301 don't works. any ideas?

```
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    Redirect 301 /index.php?id=4 site.com/newdirectory/
```

Comment: -1: why `order allow,deny` if you're going to deny from all & please define 'not working'.

Comment: I have this redirect: Redirect 301 /index.php?id=4 site.com/newdirectory/ and this not working

Comment: You already said that, how does that answer my questions?

Comment: With: order allow,deny / allow from all - I allow access to all

Comment: Yes... I know! So why even do that?

Comment: Why not? What is wrong there?

Comment: What does "don't works" look like? What version of Apache are you using? (Bear in mind your allow,deny syntax will be [invalid in 2.4 out of the box](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html), regardless of whether it's a sensible thing to be writing...)

Comment: @MattGibson my apache version is 2.4.9. And the last line Redirect 301 don't works.

Comment: ... ... ... I'm giving up...

Answer (score 1):

`order` directive is not needed just take it out. Also you cannot match query string in `Redirect` directive use `RewriteCond` of `mod_rewrite` instead like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /newdirectory/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: @anuhava  Just a note that the `[NC]` flag in this case should be on the `RewriteCond`, not just the `RewriteRule`.  Also, by default `[R]` issues a `302` (temporary) redirect—so it's unnecessary to specify a response code unless you wish to issue another type or redirect. (For anyone who didn't know you can change the response code, you can technically use any code—but only those in the 3xx range will work without error. You can also refer to the most common types by keyword: `temp` == `302`, `permanent` = `301`, and `seeother` = `303`.)